# how to select next instance of a selector with possibly intervening classes

Tags: jquery

I'd like to be able to select the next instance of a specific selector such as .ajax-loader in the following. I tried .next('.ajax-loader') but didn't seem to work and since there could be intervening classes, just simply next() wouldn't work. Here's my markup and a fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.click-me').on('click',function(){
    $(this).next().html('here i am');
  });
});​
```

html:

```
<button class='click-me'>JT</button>
<div class='other-loader'>other loader</div><div class='ajax-loader'></div><br />
<button class='click-me'>JU</button><div class='ajax-loader'></div><br />
```

In the first example, how could I progamatically say the next instance of ajax-loader? Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HAJLP/2/

thx in advance

Comment: are there any reasons why you can't put the button and the loader in the same div? that would make things simpler.

Comment: thx - i understand that would make it simpler but I would like to have maximum flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `nextAll()` with `:first`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.click-me').on('click',function(){
     $(this).nextAll('.ajax-loader:first').html('here i am');
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click-me').on('click',function(){
        $(this).find("~ .ajax-loader:first").html('here i am');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will be less costly, as you traversing thru only div tags -

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>   $('.click-me').on('click',function(){
>       $(this).nextAll('div.ajax-loader:first').html('here i am');
>   });
> });​
> ```